# Read Large CSV from S3 using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, compression

I have multiple compressed (.gzip) csv file in S3 which I wish to parse using preferably Lambda. The largest compressed file seen so far is 80MB. On decompressing, the file size becomes 1.6GB. It is approximately that a single uncompressed file can be approximately 2GB (the file be stored in compressed in S3).

After parsing, I am interested in selected rows from the csv file. I do not expect the memory used by filtered rows to be more than 200MB.

However, given Lambda's limit on time(15 min) & memory (3GB), is using Lambda for such use case a feasible option in longer run? Any alternatives to consider?

Comment: This usage pattern is better suitable for [S3 Select](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/s3-glacier-select/) which supports CSV and is designed to do what you described.

Comment: Thanks. My google search didn't make me aware of such API.